Robot framework - set a variable to a list of dictionaries, if it isn't already
I'm having a variable ${agent} which can be a list of dictionaries or a dictionary
for ex: [{1:2}] or simply {1:2}
if the variable is already a list of dictionaries, do nothing, ${agent} remains the same
if the variable type is a dictionary, then convert it to the list of dictionaries and assign it back to the same variable
before operation: ${agent} = {1:2}
after operation: ${agent} =[{1:2}]
how do I do this?
I tried Set Variable If and Run keyword If, and unable to find a solution

Use the python's function isinstance() to get its type, and do the conversation based on its outcome:
IF    isinstance($agent, dict) 
    ${agent}=   Create List    ${agent}    # create a new variable with the same name - a list, with one member, the old value
END

The isinstance() is better in this case than type() as it will march subclasses of dict.
And $var (vs {var}) is direct access to the variable, not its value.

You can use Set Variable If built-in function:
*** Variables ***
${agent}    {1:2}

*** Test Cases ***
Convert to List of Dictionaries
    Log To Console    Before operation: ${agent}
    ${is_dict}=    Evaluate    isinstance(${agent}, dict)
    ${agent}=   Set Variable If    ${is_dict}==True     [${agent}]      ${agent}
    Log To Console    After operation: ${agent}

I tested the code with two conditions; agent is a dictionary ({1:2}) and agent is a list of dictionaries ([{1:2}]). You can see the results in the below attachments:


